# Shopify button into Flutter

Tags: flutter, shopify

I would like to add a shopify buy button in my flutter web app.
My understanding is that the only way to do this is by using HtmlElementView.

My attempt is in the 2 next files. I do not get any error. But at the same time the button is not displayed. The HTML file is correct. I can correctly display it in a HTML on-line render tool.

shopify.dart
[image]

index.html

[image]